# Sort by nested fields in json in Power Automate

Tags: json, sorting, nested, power-automate

I'm trying to sort a JSON String in Power Automate by a nested field called "orderHint".
My JSON String looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "5134",
        "value": {
            "isChecked": false,
            "title": "This is another test",
            "orderHint": "8585298133570680672PF"
        },
        "lastModifiedDateTime": "2022-12-23T11:06:28.4256622Z"
    },
    {
        "id": "26576",
        "value": {
            "isChecked": true,
            "title": "This is a test",
            "orderHint": "8585498133570680672DE"
        },
        "lastModifiedDateTime": "2022-12-23T11:06:28.4256622Z"
    }
]
```

When I'm trying to sort by "orderHint", I get an error:
"'The template language function 'sort' did not find the named sortField 'orderHint' on one or more objects in the array."

I'm using the following expression:

```
sort(variables('varArrayChecked'), 'value/orderHint')
```

Sorting by other fields works fine, e.g.:

```
sort(variables('varArrayChecked'), 'id')
```

Is there any way how I can sort by a nested field in a JSON String?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the structure of each item need to stay as it is? i.e. what if it was flattened so that each property was on the same level?

Comment: I'm getting the JSON directly from Microsoft Planner Checklist-Item.

Comment: I understand that but are you ok to flatten it and work with it that way?  I'll give you an answer and you can take it or leave it.

Comment: Thank you very much your answer! I would be totally ok, if this was flattened for further processing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Advanced Data Operations` connector as it will do it for you in a single step.

The `Flatten Object Array` step is perfect for the payload you've provided.

You can see that it will take the data, flatten it and you have the ability to sort it on the way out (noting that the `Array` variable contains the exact JSON you provided in your question) ...

[image: Flatten Object Array]

***Note:** Balance Output must be set to true in order for the sorting to occur.*

**Result**

This is the resulting JSON order by `orderHint` ascending.

```
[
  {
    "id": "5134",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2022-12-23T11:06:28",
    "value/isChecked": false,
    "value/orderHint": "8585298133570680672PF",
    "value/title": "This is another test"
  },
  {
    "id": "26576",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2022-12-23T11:06:28",
    "value/isChecked": true,
    "value/orderHint": "8585498133570680672DE",
    "value/title": "This is a test"
  }
]
```

... and to show it in descending order (which is obvious, but simply change the sort order object value from `Asc` to `Desc`) ...

```
[
  {
    "id": "26576",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2022-12-23T11:06:28",
    "value/isChecked": true,
    "value/orderHint": "8585498133570680672DE",
    "value/title": "This is a test"
  },
  {
    "id": "5134",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2022-12-23T11:06:28",
    "value/isChecked": false,
    "value/orderHint": "8585298133570680672PF",
    "value/title": "This is another test"
  }
]
```

Comment: Hi Skin, thank you for your fast answer! I didn't know about this cool Premium Connector yet. However, unfortunately, I can not use it in our project, as it costs money. :-(
I will need to find another solution for either flattening the JSON structure manually or implementing the sorting manually.

Comment: FYI, the costs for this connector have just been drastically reduced. Not sure if that changes anything for you.